Joining and standardizing Country names in Tableau from different sources
I am calculating some metrics and need to standardize Country names on all sides in order to calculate it on a country level.
I have a transaction file consisting of two sql queries and external excel file.
Country 1 Column        - First SQL
Country 2 Column        - Second SQL
Country Combined Column - Calculated field
Country Excel Column    - Excel Column
The Country Combined was made by:
    IF [data (TI)] = [data (PI)] THEN
    [hotel_country (TI)]  // or [hotel_country (PI)] since they are the same
ELSEIF NOT ISNULL([data (TI)]) THEN
    [hotel_country (TI)]
ELSE
    [hotel_country (PI)]
END

What I need to do is match Country Combined to Country Excel columns in order to country level calculations.


Please add some clarity around your image and describe where it fits into your question.

You might be looking for the contains function in this case.
Something like:
IF CONTAINS([country combined], [country excel]) //if country excel is in country combined, return true
THEN [country combined] //whatever field you want returned if your above condition is met.
END

